# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MemberDetailsComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object])

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am getting this error for my component. I understand that this is the problem with injecting "AppService" in to MemberDetailsComponent. But I do not understand what is the issue here. I verified that polyfills.js contains below line

`import 'core-js/es7/reflect';`

I am struggling for few days. Any help here please.

The error is

```
 MemberDetailsComponent should create
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MemberDetailsComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MemberDetailsComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
    at syntaxError (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1270:17)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:11171:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:11064:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10683:24)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10545:23)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24119:55)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24118:72)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24115:75)
```

app.module.ts

```
export const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'members',
    component: MembersComponent
  },
    {
        path: 'details',
        component: MemberDetailsComponent
      },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

// Notice how both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule imported...choices, choices!
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, BannerComponent, MemberDetailsComponent, MembersComponent, LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true }),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DialogModule
  ],
  providers: [AppService, HttpClient],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

app.service.ts

```
    @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  api = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
  username: string;
  DEBUG: Boolean = false;
  editMode: Boolean = false;
  memberDialog = false;
  members = [];
  member:Member = new Member();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      if (this.DEBUG) {
          this.api = 'http://localhost:3000';
        } else {
          this.api = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
        }
  }
  -- service methods --
```

member-details-component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// This interface may be useful in the times ahead...
export class Member {
id:number;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
jobTitle: string;
team: string;
status: string;
}

@Component({
selector: 'app-member-details',
templateUrl: './member-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./member-details.component.css']
})
export class MemberDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
memberModel: Member = new Member();
memberForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
alertType: String = "";
alertMessage: String ="";
teams = [];

constructor( public appService: AppService, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
  this.memberForm = this.fb.group({
              firstName: ['', Validators.required],
              lastName: ['', Validators.required],
              jobTitle: ['', Validators.required],
              team: ['', Validators.required],
              status: ['', Validators.required]
          });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.appService.getTeams().subscribe((teams) => (this.teams = teams));
}
ngOnChanges() {}
onSubmit() {
   -- logic
}
}
```

member-details-component.spec.ts

```
 import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject  } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MemberDetailsComponent } from './member-details.component';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';



// Bonus points!
describe('MemberDetailsComponent', () => {
 let component: MemberDetailsComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<MemberDetailsComponent>;
 let appService: AppService;
 let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ MemberDetailsComponent ],
     imports: [HttpClientModule],
           providers: [
             { provide: AppService, useValue: {} },
             {
               provide: Router,
               useClass: class {
                 navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
               }
             }
           ]
   })
   .compileComponents();
 }));

 beforeEach(() => {
   appService = TestBed.get(AppService);
   httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberDetailsComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});
```

Code in StackBlitz :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8damnn

Comment: Generally a circular dependency, please provide a stackblitz in order to reproduce your bug.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just edited and added StackBlitx link

Comment: Please provide a working stackblitz there is lot of error, is not just pasting your code inside, make sure everything work in order to see your bug.

Comment: I added environment files. Now you see the exact error that I am facing. Appreciate your response

Comment: This project has nodejs server and json-server. On my local nodejs is running at 8000 and json-server running at 3000. Not sure what to use instead of "localhost" in app.service.js and server.js in StackBlitz. You can see the error anyway without any backend. But this is FYI

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your project, the error was because your are importing the class 'Member' from the component member-details into the service App, and the service App is imported everywhere and make a circular reference for the class Member.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpqftw

I created a folder `Models` with the class `Member` inside, is a better way, if you need to share models create a separate file for it. 
I have change the importe everywhere.